# Access Runtime 2010 Disappeared from Domain Computers - Deleted GPO

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, microsoft-access

My organization runs a domain with an Access front end based upon and SQL Express Database.
99% of our users are using the 2010 Runtime version of access.

The installed DB literally disappeared from a ***few computers*** this morning.

When I try an modify/repair/uninstall/reinstall both the Database/access runtime 2010 neither seems to work. (Both appear as installed, though neither appear in the Start/Search or on the desktop as an icon. At this point I have no way to launch our database).

One of the users who had Access Runtime disappear grabbed a saved version of the Database accdb file from my folder and dragged it to their desktop.

**Low and behold it worked.**  Why?! They are now able to use the Access runtime/ view our database.

But it creates a locked version of the Access icon on their desktop while they are using it. The newly copied version of the Database still leaves an icon on their desktop (that they can continue to use)

Yesterday I was messing around with an old GPO that had an OLDER package of the Access database linked but not enabled. I tried to change it, to get it to only target specific shadow groups when the users logged into new computers. I ended up deleting it entirely. It was my understanding that this GPO published the Database when new users logged in. The existing path linked a package an older version of the Access database installer that we haven't used for years.

I know I very likely messed something up.

Looking at the event log for one of the users. I noticed that the Database was uninstalled as soon as the User logged into their computer this morning.

Can anyone give me some direction? Maybe just help me ask the right question.

Comment: Some things are not clear: Where is the SQL Express DB installed ? On each clients ? You say that your users are using the 2010 runtime, they use the runtime to start an Access front-end to connect to your SQL Express DB ? how should using an older version of the DB not have worked? Why the GPOs are involved here ? the Access file is copied by GPO ?

Comment: The SQL express DB is installed on a domain controller. Yes, They use access runtime to connect to the database. I have a full version of access on my computer. I suppose using an older version of the DB wouldn't make any difference as it would only effect the form view in our access runtime UI. The GPO's were created long ago (before me). We have custom ones for logon (to map server drives, connect printers, install access (disabled, but linked { I think}, now deleted), and then the default GPO settings. I think the access file (the packaged installer) was linked and meant to be installed on

Comment: any new user profiles that were joined to the domain.

Comment: I believe the created GPO (labeled Access install), was meant to grab the installer for a version of access stored on our network drives. I was then meant to install the runtime and the database on said user's profile when they logged on for the first time. It seems like old GPO created specifically for new users.